# WindowManger notifies activity

Tags: linux, window-managers

I'm looking for a tiling window manager that support notification of activity.

What I mean for it?

Let's say that I have a terminal command running on workspace 1, because it is a very slow command I would like to be notify when the prompt appears again. When it is running I'm working on workspace 2.

Another example, I usually keep the thunderbird on a workspace. Let's say that it is workspace 4. When I receive a new email, the workspace 4 notifies me. Why not use the thunderbird notification? It is huge and usually take all the space of my terminal when I'm working with 2 or 3 opened.

Someone knows a tile WM that supports this type of notification?

Another good example is the screen command. I can configure it to monitor the terminal and it notifies me when I'm in other terminal.

Thanks.

Comment: What window manager are you using now? Do you have a way to get thunderbird and your terminal to do something such that your window manager *can* notify you?

Comment: I'm using i3. I changed the configuration to notify me via i3bar.I've a script that keep looking for change in the INBOX directory of thunderbird, but I'd like something based in visual change if possible.

Comment: I would try and see if [wmctrl](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/)'s `-a` option on a hidden window causes `i3` to display some sort of notification for the window or whether it forces it to be the active window or does nothing. If that performs a notification that you like that should help with thunderbird. Doing this for a terminal is trickier though setting the terminal to ring the bell might also trigger a wm notification of some sort. (And some terminals support an option to request activity from the wm which can also trigger notification).

Comment: hum... I'll see if I can change terminal. About wmctrl, I will give a try using the -r and -b option. The option -a I think is not a good thing, I'd tried a similar command and I don't like the behavior of change my focus.

Comment: If it changes your focus then your wm is insufficiently protecting you from that and/or not instructing applications that it supports being requested to tell the user that the window has had activity. It *shouldn't* do that if wmctrl is being well behaved and your wm works. (I will say I don't know that wmctrl is well behaved.)